# Pandas groupby based on a condition from another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a df such as example below and I am looking to identify users who message the same text within a given time period, such as <= 60 minutes for the example:

```
user = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
text = ['hello','hello','whats up','not now','not now','hello']
times = ['2010-09-14 16:51:00','2010-09-14 15:59:00',
        '2010-09-14 15:14:00','2010-09-14 14:55:00','2010-09-14 15:47:00','2010-09-14 15:29:00']

df = pd.DataFrame({'userid':user,'message':text,'time':times})
```

My current method groups the text by a list of users who messaged each text:

```
group = df.groupby('message')['userid'].apply(list)
```

Then I return all the possible combinations of userid's from each list as an array of pair values and then retrieve the userid-text for each instance as a key for retrieving the time of each message for each pair from the original df

This method works but I have been trying to find a better way of grouping the users of each different text conditionally based on whether the time between each instance is less than a specified period of time, say 60 minutes for this example, taken as the difference between the two messages from the users. So "hello" for users 1 and 2 is less than 60 minutes apart so pass the condition and be added to the list for "hello".

The expected output for the example would therefore be:

```
       userid
"hello" [1,2,6]
"not not" [4,5]
```

I haven't found any exact or similar solutions so any help is really appreciated. It may be that my approach to the problem is wrong!

Comment: could you please provide the expected output?

Comment: also - when you say 'within 60 minutes' - does it have to be within the same hour (e.g. 12:15 and 12:45), or does it refer to 12:45 and 13:15 as well? (less than 60 minutes but different hour).

Comment: The output from the conditional groupby would be each text with a list of userids who messaged that text within 60 minutes. It is the difference between the two messages, so across hours is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it's the most elegant solution - but here's one using `group-by` and `rolling`. The advantage of this method is that it can work for large sets of data. It doesn't create the full cartesian product of all the users and times who sent the same message.

```
res = [] 

def collect_users(x):
    if len(x) > 1: 
        s = set(x) 
        if res and res[-1].issubset(s):
            res.pop()

        res.append(set(x))
    return 0 

df.groupby("message").rolling("3600s").agg(collect_users)
```

The result comes as a list of sets:

```
[{1.0, 2.0, 6.0}, {4.0, 5.0}]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, this looks great I like the logic. Its seems to work well on a slice of my data so I will see how it goes on the full set. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a `groupby` to find the next matching message chronologically, `merge` it to the original dataframe, and then filter to things where the message gap is < 1 hour:

```
In [402]: df2 = df.merge(df.sort_values("time").groupby("message").shift(), left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=["_source", "_target"])

In [403]: df2.loc[df2['time_source'].sub(df2['time_target']).lt("1h"), ["message", "userid_source", "userid_target"]].astype('O')
Out[403]:
   message  userid_source  userid_target
0    hello              1              2
1    hello              2              6
4  not now              5              4
```

Note that in your current data, 2 and 6 messaged `hello` 30 minutes apart and also appears here.